Python video library with fast frame access
I'm using pims library (https://github.com/soft-matter/pims) to access frames in a .MOV file with over 25K frames, 3840 × 2160, H.264 (High Profile), 60fps. Here are the timings on a fairly fast PC, starting from file open:

frame #100: 2.97s
frame #1,000: 28.39s
frame #10,000: 280.19s

Is there a library with faster frame access time? It can access the nearest key frame, if it does speed things up. Also, fast access to reduced resolution frames would be acceptable.
Standard Ubuntu video viewer allows me to forward/rewind with a slider and has nearly instantaneous response. There should be a fast library somewhere.

I made a sanity test with ffmpeg and accessing frame #10,000 with ffmpeg -ss 00:02:46.33 -i v1.MOV -frames:v 1 f10k.png is practically instantaneous.
